# How to add bash variable to text file after matched keywords?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file(yaml) with the term "name:" and I would like to add variable($var) from bash and insert into yaml. I am able to find the key words and add variable after that:

```
sed -i "s/name:/& $var/" "yaml file"
```

However the variable keep added up in yaml file, as name: abc def ghi(I would like to have single name only)

How to fix it? also how can I add some text after $var, something like "$var-role"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the whole line, not just `name:`. So add `.*` to the regexp to match everything after it on the line.

```
sed -i "s/name:.*/name: $var/" "yaml file"
```

You can't use `&` in this version because that would include the rest of the line as well.

If you want to add more text, just put it after the variable.

```
sed -i "s/name:.*/name: ${var}-role/" "yaml file"
```

Put `{}` around the variable name to separate it from the following text (not really needed when the text begins with `-`, but would be needed if it began with a character that can be part of a variable name).

Comment: how to apply the change on second/third occurrence only? I tried flags /g and it does all global changes; however I input /1 or /2 and it did nothing.

Comment: second/third occurrence on each line? Or second/third occurrence in the file?

Comment: `/g`, `/1`, and `/2` modifiers refers to multiple replacements on the same line.

Comment: in the file. I read some articles that the flags only changes through the line. Thank you

Comment: There may be a way to do it, but I don't know advanged `sed` features. I would use `awk` or a scripting language.